# Tokio_postgres hangs when trying to perform simple query

Tags: postgresql, rust, rust-tokio, tokio-postgres

I'm trying to connect to a postgres server from my Rust program, but I can't seem to run even simple queries, they just hang with no error or output.

I start my database with:

`docker run -p 9897:5432 --name postgres-server -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres -d postgres`

And try to connect to it:

```rust
#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    println!("Connecting to Postgres.");
    let (client, conn) = tokio_postgres::Config::new()
        .user("postgres")
        .password("postgres")
        .host("localhost")
        .port(9897)
        .dbname("postgres")
        .connect(tokio_postgres::NoTls)
        .await
        .unwrap();
    println!("Connected to Postgres.");

    client.simple_query("SELECT 1")
        .await
        .unwrap();
    
    println!("Query finished!");
}
```

With these versions of tokio & tokio-postgres

```ini
[dependencies]
tokio = {version="1.27.0", features = ["rt", "full"]}
tokio-postgres = "0.7.8"
```

But it never finishes the query. I am running on a MacBook Pro M1.

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation of [tokio_postgres::Client::simple_query](https://docs.rs/tokio-postgres/0.7.8/tokio_postgres/struct.Client.html#method.simple_query):

> Executes a sequence of SQL statements using the simple query protocol, returning the resulting rows.
>
> **Statements should be separated by semicolons**.

Your statement is never completed, because it is never executed, since you didn't finish it.

Note that this is crate-specific behavior. For example [sqlx](https://crates.io/crates/sqlx) crate in it's [query](https://docs.rs/sqlx/0.7.1/sqlx/fn.query.html) function expects a single query without terminating semicolon.